# FBX exported model's texture tiling issue in Reality Converter

Tags: arkit, fbx, usdz, reality-converter

I am exporting an FBX character from Maya to Reality Converter. In Maya, I base the settings on the "Autodesk Media and Entertainment" profile, I embed media to make sure textures are exported, and I set the scale to meters.
The textures work well in Maya, but in Reality Converter they appear tiled. The same character downloaded as DAE from the Mixamo website has the textures displaying correctly in RC. Also, the exported FBX looks fine in FBX review, which leads me to believe this has to do with the way the FBX is read inside Reality Converter. The export converts the units to meters, which is the only scaling factor I can think of in the scene. However, typically unit scaling does not affect UV tiling in any 3D software I worked in.

[This is how textures appear in Maya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ1vP.png)
and [this is how they appear once in Reality Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzufm.png)
I have found several posts around the web describing the issue, but none outlining a solution
Any suggestions?